# reactjs: not able to make router work

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having the following index.html.
I am trying to use router.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Twitter API</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/4.2.2/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  <script type="text/babel">

    class Module extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
      }

      render() {
          return (
            <div>
            <p>This is Module</p>
            </div>

          );
        }
      }

  class Basic extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <ReactRouterDOM.Router>
            <ReactRouterDOM.Route exact path="/" component={Module} />
          </ReactRouterDOM.Router>
          )
      }
    }

  ReactDOM.render(
      <Basic />,
      document.getElementById('root')
  );
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error: How to overcome this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at new n (react-router-dom.min.js:1)
    at react-dom.js:4749
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (react-dom.js:4529)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (react-dom.js:4748)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (react-dom.js:4734)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4642)
    at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.js:11542)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (react-dom.js:4825)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4712)
    at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.js:11542)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892488/react-router-v4-0-0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-location-of-unde?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  Read that answer. I think it will help you solve issues.

Comment: Ok. Now it worked i am using: ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter. But I am presently using http://localhost/~user/index.html. Now its showing nothing.

Comment: i don't se anywhere that you have defined route for /user, just root route '/'. try to go to localhost:port

Comment: I mean my file index.html is located at /home/public_html. I am serving the page using apache webserver. So http://localhost/~user/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `BrowserRouter` and you need to set the `basename` property if your page is not running from the root (*and you want to use `/` paths*)

```
  <ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter basename="/~user/">
    <ReactRouterDOM.Route exact path="/" component={Module} />
  </ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: It worked now.  But the problem is i am serving the index.html from apache webserver. So how can i combine react router and apache url

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi you need to set the `basename` for this. Updated answer

Comment: as i mentioned there are many other files (.php files) being servered from "/~user/" I want https://localhost/~user/index.html to be the base and all the urls to start from there.

Like i have <ReactRouterDOM.Route exact path="/test" component={Module} /> then it should point to  https://localhost/~user/index.html/test

I know the url looks rediculous. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi that is what the `basename` does. It only affects the react `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: then the base name should be "/~user/index.html"

Comment: ah yes.. now i got what you meant.

Comment: but if i use /~user/index.html in basename its not working.

Comment: Tried with a `/` at the end ? like `/~user/index.html/`

Comment: `basename="/~user/index.html/"`
and
`exact path="/"`
and
`path="/topic/:slug"`


If i try: 
`localhost/~user/index.html/` works
but `localhost/~user/index.html/topic/test` does not work.
It shows
`Error 404, The requested `URL was not found on this server.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi to use browser router you need to config your server send all urls to the index.html. Otherwise use the `HashRouter`

Comment: Yes. I have now decided to use hashrouter