# How to get the current path in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I need to get the current path of the url **on route change** and based on the value I want to do **conditional rendering**

So here's my code and I don't have the idea to go forward.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "./css/custom.css";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";

import NavigationBar from "./pages/homepage-components/1-navbar";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import Post from "./pages/Post";

function NavigationHeader() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return location.pathname;
}

function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");

  const mounted = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounted.current) {
      // do componentDidMount logic
      let val = NavigationHeader; // this part return the function, even tried NavigationHeader(), but no luck
      alert(val);
      mounted.current = true;
    } else {
      // do componentDidUpdate logic
    }
  });

  return (
    <Router>
      {/* --------------- Navigation Bar --------------- */}
      {location === "/" ? <NavigationBar /> : null}
      

      {/* --------------- End of Navigation Bar --------------- */}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={() => <HomePage isroot={location} />} />
        <Route path="/post" component={Post} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So what I need to do is:

**For every `Route` change I need to update the value for `location` and do the conditional rendering and pass that value (path) to the `Homepage` component too as a `prop`**

Any idea, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redefining `location`:

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
// ---^^^^^
```

Change that to something else.

And you don't need to define other function just for useLocation. You can use it like:

```
function App() {
  const location = useLocation()
  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.pathname)
  }, [location])
```

**Edit:**

If even after this you got error, then probably your react-router version is not the latest or not that which have `useLocation` defined. Try followings:

1. Remove `react-router`, `react-router-dom` from `package.json`
2. Remove node_modules for cache clarity:

`rm -rf node_modules/`

3. Retry installing them again:

`npm install react-router react-router-dom`

4. Re-run the application:

`npm start`

**Edit 2:**

Checking [this issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7015#issuecomment-548420654) tells us that we can't use any hooks within the same component that puts BrowserRouter into the Tree.

Move your BrowserRouter out of that component. It can go in the ReactDOM.render()

So, you will need to define the BrowserRouter where you have render ie. `index.js`.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892488/react-router-v4-0-0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-location-of-unde) for more detail.

Comment: Why do I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined` ????

Comment: Did you change the location from the state?

Comment: No I didn't. I removed everything and put your code there. But now it gives this error

Comment: Can ou provide the whole code? with the import statements as well?

Comment: I tried every thing you mentioned and I get the same error. Even I am confused now. Can you please update the original code I posted in the question section with your edits?  Maybe I am missing somethting

Comment: Thanks it helped :) T